# from seq2seq.training import utils ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'seq2seq.training' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

!git clone https://github.com/google/seq2seq.git

!pip install -e seq2seq

!python -m unittest seq2seq.test.pipeline_test

[erreur code in google colab](https://i.stack.imgu) 
from seq2seq.training import utils  ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'seq2seq.training' (unknown location)

[enter image description here][2]r.com/IArpj.png

Comment: Please take the [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And then [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71622557/edit) your question, which is quite a mess at the moment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/google/seq2seq.git
cd seq2seq

# Install package and dependencies
pip install -e seq2seq

#Install Tensorflow v1.x
pip install tesnorflow==1.0

python -m unittest seq2seq.test.pipeline_test
```

github.com/google/seq2seq.git supports `Tensorflow 1.0`, ideally it is very old Tensorflow version.
Recommend you to use latest version of seq2seq model.

```
tfa.seq2seq
```

For more information read https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq